# Validate Date and Time in the Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, format

I have a datepicker plugin to pop-up a calendar view to allow users to select a date + time, however the format which it produces is:

```
May 9, 2016 8:30 AM
```

When storing to the database, I need the format to be:

```
2016-09-05 08:30:00
```

In the controller of my application, I have:

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    Entry::create($request->all());
    return redirect('entries');
}
```

Which saves the users form input, however it doesn't save the datetime due to the incorrect format. I have tried creating a new function to format the date before entering it into the database.

```
public function formatDate($data)
{
    $returnDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m G:i:s', $data);
    return $returnDate->format('Y-d-m G:i:s');
}
```

However when I call the function from the save function, it says undefined function. Am I doing something wrong or what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: $returnDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m G:i:s', $data);  here $returnDate  returns false.so error occurs

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the correct format for `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. Create from format means, you have to tell a pattern to match any information in the given date. For your date, the pattern is:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y g:i A', $data);
```

Here is a demo: https://eval.in/567629

A list of all format options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Both functions are inside the model?
If so, how are you trying to call the formatDate function?

You could use an anonymous function instead, try:

`$formatted_date = function() use ($data) {
    $returnDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m G:i:s', $data);
    return $returnDate->format('Y-d-m G:i:s');
};`

Inside your controller or model.

Comment: Both functions are in the same model. I've tried calling the formatDate in the `save` function, but it states function undefined so my above code doesn't include it, I'm still trying to experiment with it. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, the created_at and updated_at are casted to Carbon objects

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

With your date, you could do the same thing

`class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'your_date'];
}`

then, when saving the date, it will be cast to the correct format.

Give that a try and let us know how you get on!

Answer (score 0):

For example;

```
$data = "May 9, 2016 8:30 AM";

return  date('Y-d-m H:i:s',strtotime($data));
```